# Is there a definition that defines the set of all factors of a natural number?

Tags: definition

So let's say that you have the number $n=12$. The factors of $12$ are $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $6$, and $12$. I'm wondering if there's some definition that when you plug in a natural number $n$, it will give you the set of all of it's factors. So, if I plugged in $12$ for $n$, I would get the set ${1,2,3,4,6,12}$, in no particular order of course. Is there such a thing? If so, what is it?

Edit: Since $1$ and $n$ are always factors of $n$, I can get as far as ${1,n} \subseteq F $ where $F$ is the set of factors of $n$.

Comment: You seem to have just defined it. I have no idea what else you are looking for.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ??? So you're saying I can only divide 12 by 1 and 12, and not 2, 3, 4, or 6? That's just absurd. Reread the question and tell me what I didn't make clear, I'll fix it.

Comment: When did he say that?

Comment: No, I am saying that "all the factors" is already a definition.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No I mean like a mathematically written definition, not words. Maybe I should've said for formula?

Comment: @5xum I assumed he was mentioning my edit, in which I said that 1 and n are a subset of the factors of n. My mistake, he wasn't.

Comment: @Sam: What's wrong with words?

Comment: The set of all the numbers which are algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, it is known as the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$. This is something like this what it is asked by @Sam.

Comment: The set you are looking for is $d(n)=\{m\in \mathbb{N} :  m \text{ divides } n\}$, but the question does not make much sense, since you can define whatever you want. If you are asking for some kind of map that given a natural number $n$ will return the set of all of its divisors, probably you can't do that via some formula. Otherwise cryptography would have no point at all.

Comment: You mean $1, n \in F$ and not $1, n \subseteq F$ which is something different.

Comment: @Frunobulax the first symbol you mentioned is for elements. $1, n$ isn't an element, it's a set containing elements. That's what the subset symbol is for.

Comment: @Frunobulax so using the "element of" symbol would be incorrect... I think??

Comment: If you want to combine objects into a set, then you need to add curly braces around them, so you'd need to write $\{1,n\}\subseteq F$.  If you write something like $1,n\in F$ without braces, then the usual convention is to understand this as an abbreviation for $1 \in F \land n \in F$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question indicates that you do know the definition: the set of factors of the positive integer $n$ contains just the positive integers $m$ that divide $n$. If you'd rather not use the word "divide" in the definition, then it's the integers $m$ for which there is an integer $k$ such that $km=n$.

That definition does use words. Writing it more compactly this way (as in @AlbertoDebernardi 's comment):

$$
d(n)=\{m∈N:m | n\}
$$

(where "$|$" is the symbol for "divides") doesn't really make it more "mathematical". Those symbols are all defined with words.

When you talk about "plugging in" an integer and getting the set of factors you may be thinking about a computer program. At http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factors_of_an_integer you will find programs (in many languages) that accept an $n$ as input and return the list of its factors.

The python example:

> factors(45)
>   [1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 45]

Comment: Downvote without a comment? I wonder why.

Comment: My terminology was messed up. I meant something like the following answer in which Scheodinger'scats provided this.

Comment: it takes time to type have some patience :)

Comment: Oh wait sorry never mind you did provide a definition.

Comment: To formalize the other "multiplicative" approach:  $$ d(n) = \{m \in \mathbb{N} \; : \; \exists k \in \mathbb{N} \; km = n \}$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to define such a set for $n \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$ in the following way:

> $$\{x\large|n=\prod_i^mp_i^{a_i} \land x=\prod_i^mp_i^{k_i} \,\,
>   \text{where} \,\, 0\le k_i\le a_i\}$$

Comment: A Downvote without an explanation...?

Comment: This answer is needlessly complicated, and fails to include that the $p_i$ should be prime numbers.

Comment: @BenMillwood This is a standard notation for any natural number from the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: Why an answer that depends on unique factorization, while the concept makes sense in much more generality?

Comment: The question asked for something where one could "plug in a natural number $n$". So we're in $\mathbb N$ and have unique factorization. The fact that the factorization can generate the factors in this way is a useful observation. I would possibly prefer a few more words and shorter formulas, but OP seems to want everything in a formula, so ...